# ошибка в виджете nav

Tags: yii2

попытался сделать автоматическое добавление пунктов в меню при добавлении записей в табдицу firmcat в виджете nav вот тактим образом

```
if(isset($firm)){
                            function menuitemFirm($firm){

                                $arr=array();
                                foreach($firm as $cat){
                                    array_push($arr,[
                                            'label'=>Html::tag('span',Html::img(iconFirm($cat->id)),['class'=>'col-md-8 noMobile']).''. Html::tag('span',$cat->title,['class'=>'col-md-16 col-sm-12 col-xs-24']),
                                            'url'=>['/firmcat/list?id='.$cat->id],
                                            'linkOptions'=>[
                                                'class' => $cat->id.' col-md-24 col-xs-24'
                                                ],

                                            'encode' => false
                                            ]);
                                }
                                return $arr;
                            }

                            $menuItems[]=[
                                'label' => 'По производителям',
                                'url' =>'#',
                                'items' => [ menuitemFirm($firm)],
                                'dropDownOptions'=>[
                                        'class'=>'dropdown-menu col-md-24 col-xs-24'

                                ],
                            ];
                        }
```

где $firm это $firm=Firmcat::find()->all(); получил ошибку The 'label' option is required. В Firmcat две записи если  записать var_dump($arr) получу

```
array(2) {
 [0]=> array(4) { 
    ["label"]=> string(212) "Алуштинский эфиромасличный совхоз-завод" 
    ["url"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(18) "/firmcat/list?id=1" }
    ["linkOptions"]=> array(1) { 
        ["class"]=> string(21) "1 col-md-24 col-xs-24" } 
    ["encode"]=> bool(false) } 
[1]=> array(4) { 
    ["label"]=> string(166) "Крымская стевия" 
    ["url"]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(18) "/firmcat/list?id=2" }
    ["linkOptions"]=> array(1) { 
        ["class"]=> string(21) "2 col-md-24 col-xs-24" 
    } 
    ["encode"]=> bool(false) } }
```

почему возникает такая ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В свойстве items должен быть массив, каждый элемент которого описывает каждый пункт, в вашем случае в items массив всего с одним элементом, т.к. функция ваша и так возвращает массив массивов, а вы еще раз в массив оборачиваете

```
'items' => [ menuitemFirm($firm)],
```

замените просто на

```
'items' => menuitemFirm($firm),
```